# collection check boxes in view select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, haml

in the view

```
= form.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Item::Category.all, :id, :name, checked: "#{@search.try(:category_ids)}"
```

returns

```
"[\"3\", \"\"]"
```

but it should produce

```
["3", ""]
```

Why does it happen?

```
@search.try(:category_ids) is ["3", ""]
```

Comment: It's adding slashes to escape the quotes you already have in the string, this is a normal and correct behavior

Comment: cool, but when I try to use - checked: "#{@search.try(:category_ids)}" the check boxes are not checked in the form, but when I substitute it with - checked: ["2", "3"], it works fine. what do I do wrong? I also updated the view

Comment: Why are u even putting quotes, just do `checked: @search.try(:category_ids)`

Comment: can I just ask you one more thing please - I have = form.text_field :price, id: 'slider', type: 'text', :input_html => { :value => "#{@search.try(:price)}" } where I use a bootstrap slider. what do I do wrong here? sorry I am still learning here

Comment: what's `input_html` for?, also again change value to `value: @search.try(:price)`

Comment: thanks a lot, I just need to fiddle with JS now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just remove the quotes, it's unnecessary

```
= form.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Item::Category.all, :id, :name, checked: @search.try(:category_ids)
```